# Can Wernicke's aphasia lead to grammar deterioration?

Tags: neurolinguistics, aphasiology

Speech often (always?) deteriorates for people with post-lingual deafness. This presumably occurs because of insufficient auditory feedback.

Given that people with Wernicke's aphasia cannot comprehend language, do they also experience speech deterioration (that is, speech becoming disjointed and/or ungrammatical) over time as a result of hearing themselves speak, but not understanding the sounds they produce?

Comment: Very interesting! I have never heard of such evolution of Wernicke's, but the suggestion totally makes sense. Btw, can you give some details of/links to the deterioration facts you refer to?

Comment: @IvanKapitonov Details re: deterioration in people with post-lingual deafness?

Comment: Oh yes! Sorry, I worded it awkwardly.

Comment: One paper that comes to mind is [Waldstein (1990)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/2269726) [1]. I'll see if my prof can recommend other texts and I'll write an update later this week. [1] Waldstein, R. S. (1990). Effects of postlingual deafness on speech production: implications for the role of auditory feedback. Journal of the Acoustical Society of America, 88(5), 2099-2114.

Comment: This might be better at [cogsci.se].

Comment: This falls within the realm of linguistics, I see no reason to migrate my question.

Comment: @fenceop Many questions are on-topic on several sites, but some sites will have people who are more experience on certain topics. There may be some psychologists here, but I think there would be more at the other site.

Comment: So you're suggesting that people hear what they say to themselves and learn from that?